# Forward one SSH user login to a different SSH server

Tags: ssh, git

I have a box with one user, say `pmg`, and on it I run Gitea in a container with its own ssh server and another user, `git`.

Currently, I have configured the main SSH server to listen on port 22, and the Gitea SSH server to listen on port 2201. With this configuration, the following logins are valid:

`ssh pmg@example.net -p 22`

`ssh git@example.net -p 2201`

However, I would like to use the same port for convenience. Is there a way to redirect the login of the user `git` to `localhost:2201`?

I tried using the following clause in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but this fails because the physical host doesn't have the user `git`:

```
Match User git
    ForceCommand ssh -t 127.0.0.1:2201
```

I can't just create a user `git` and set a password to it, because authentication for the user `git` uses public keys which users of the Gitea server can configure themselves. Since Gitea is running in a container, I could create the user `git` on the physical host, and then mount `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the physical host to `/data/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the container, but this introduces its own issues.

Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT:**
It turns out I can't use the `authorized_keys` trick for two reasons:

1. The key used for login into the physical host doesn't get forwarded to the container
2. The `authorized_keys` generated by Gitea looks something like this:

   ```
   # gitea public key
   command="/app/gitea/gitea serv key-1 --config='/data/gitea/conf/app.ini'",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAII3dF5LGP++euujygyceesqOwq8jSaKHo4NPaC2BlcIW theta
   ```